# framework to create dashboards and alarms

Tags: javascript, analytics, dashboard, bigdata

I am working on writing on a big data project in my company. We are writing software which gather a lot of data (clickstream like data). Currently we are storing this data in HBase. We plan to build analytics on top of it. We looked at OBIEE and a possible solution where the aggregated HBase data could be loaded to an Oracle instance and have OBIEE front the Oracle data. This may be a workable solution, but it has a lot of dependencies and we will be limited by Oracle's abilities (Our data is very huge).

If we were to write our own analytics portal with the abilities of mainly creating rich uis (regular reporting dashboards, custom dashboards) and business alarms, are there any frameworks which would easily allow me to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: limited by oracle's abilities? given that oracle dbs can contain exabytes of data, your "huge" had better be VERY huge.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of InfoCaptor and we just released our free platform for dashboards and BI at https://my.infocaptor.com

You might want to check out as it contains sound alerts for alarms that you are looking for

Your feedback is always appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HBase (open source/Cloud db), I do not see the reasoning of using oracle (proprietary / RDBMS). Its sort of one step back in my view. I think irrespective of complexity, scale of requirements all analytic data can be gathered by using a set of MapReduce jobs on Hadoop with help of HBase coprocessors and this data can be stored on hbase itself. For faster reads you can use a caching front end tool such as Redis / memcached.

For realtime analytic data you can use Hadoop pipeline capability.

Hope this helps. We have been using this combination since a while and the results are astounding.

Comment: You may explore GWT (Google web toolkit) to build your web ui / dashboards. It supports a number of Google visualizations.